# Como fechar conexão com o banco de dados Firebird

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, asp.net, webforms, firebird

Estou fazendo um projeto em asp.net c# web forms framework 4.5 e fiz um teste de conexão com um banco de dados Firebird, mas ao fechar a conexão ele não está fechando, usei o seguinte código para abrir e fechar:

```
string conDDNS;
FbConnection conexaoDDNS;

 protected void Abrir_Fechar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.conDDNS = "DRIVER=InterBase/Firebird(r) driver;User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=localhost:C:/AdCom/ADCOM.FDB";

            this.conexaoDDNS = new FbConnection(conDDNS);
            this.conexaoDDNS.Open();
            ListItem item = new ListItem("Conexão aberta");
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item);

            this.conexaoDDNS.Dispose();
            this.conexaoDDNS.Close();
            ListItem item2 = new ListItem("Conexão fechada");
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item2);

        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            ListItem item = new ListItem(erro.ToString());
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item);
        }

    }
```

Ja tentei usar só o comando `.Close()` mas não deu certo, tentei usar o `.Close()` e o `.Dispose()` mas também não deu certo.

Quando fiz isso debugando percebi que ao passar pelo comando `.Open()` ele abre a conexão normalmente, mas quando ele passa pelo comando `.Close()` e pelo `.Dispose()` a conexão continua aberta no firebird.

Para descobrir o número de conexões abertas no firebird estou usando o comando `select * FROM MON$ATTACHMENTS`

Answer (score 1):

Conforme principio de funcionalidade unica, sugiro que voce separe em metodos diferentes.

```
public class ConnectionFirebird
{
    private static FbConnection AbreBD()
    {
        FbConnection ConexaoBanco = new FbConnection();
        try
        {
            string _conn;
            _conn = "User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey";
            _conn += ";Database=C:\\(path_database)";
            _conn += ";Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=NONE;Role=;Connection lifetime=0;";
            _conn += "Connection timeout=7;Pooling=True;Packet Size=8192;Server Type=0";
            ConexaoBanco.ConnectionString = _conn;
            ConexaoBanco.Open();

            return ConexaoBanco;
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Falha na Tentativa de Acesso a Base de Dados Informada);
            return ConexaoBanco;
        }
    }

    public static bool TestaConn()
    {
        FbConnection Conexao;
        bool Retorno = false;

        Conexao = AbreBD();
        Retorno = false;
        if (Conexao.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            Conexao.Close();
            Retorno = true;
        }
        return Retorno;
    }
    private static void FechaBanco(IDbConnection Conn)
    {
        // Verifica se a conexão do banco de dados está aberta
        if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            Conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

*alterar (path_database)

Answer (score -2):

Meu amigo recomendo a leitura do código : [Conectando com Firebase](http://www.devmedia.com.br/conectando-em-uma-base-de-dados-firebird-com-c/11938)

Também acredito que você usar o bloco de código ([using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/yh598w02.aspx)) poderá resolver seu problema.

Abraços.

Comment: Cara eu tentei o que esta neste artigo, foi exatamente o que eu usei no projeto mas também não deu certo

Comment: @Jhonathan sua resposta tem que ser baseada no contexto da pergunta, ter conteúdo e não somente links, gostaríamos de ver respostas mais elaboradas!